# Multi module gradle project

Tags: java, gradle

I have the following gradle setup:

```
Main
    SubModule1
    SubModule2
```

the settings.gradle for the Main module is:

```
rootProject.name = 'Main'
include ':SubModule1'
include ':SubModule2'
```

When I run a submodule and I want to access local file from within the submodule project folder I need to place it in the Main project folder. Also the output is getting saved in the Main project folder, log4j for example puts all its logs for both submodules in de Main project. Can someone explain how I can change the folders to the right submodule?

I did not change de build script yet. everything is default like this one from the main build.gradle:

```
group 'com.main'
version 'v0.1'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you add your build script(s)?

Comment: @lu.koerfer I've updated my question but I did not change anything to my build.gradle yet

Comment: So you access a file from your project code and not from your build script code? Is this more of a Java problem or more of a Gradle problem?

Comment: I can access the file but I expect that my logs would go in to it submodule folder but it goes in the parent module folder. Same goes for files if it is the parent folder the program finds it but not when I put it in the submodule folder

Comment: So when I want to create a config.ini file for example I have to place it in the parent folder but this would cause a problem when I need a config.ini file for different submodules because it is only looking in the parent folder

Comment: @lu.koerfer I tried to set the project dir for each submodule by setting this in the settings.gradle of the parent module:

project('Main').projectDir = file(new File(rootDir, 'Main\\SubModule1'))

But dhat also didn't seem to work

Comment: You mean log files written by your program, am I right? Gradle has nothing to do with these files, their location just depends on the working directory you use to start your program.

Comment: @lu.koerfer do you know how I set this up correctly in Java then?